# Azure APIM Restrict verb based on Product

Tags: azure-api-management, azure-policy

We have several APIs that have various methods for reading and writing data. All APIs go though the APIM, and I am wanting to create and assign products to these APIs, but restrict to read, or write by using verbs (GET, POST, DELETE, etc).

I am thinking like create a product called "api-(name)-read" and set a policy that allows the GET verb only. There will be another product "api-(name)-write" that allows all VERBs. I see in the CORS section, I can set allowed-methods, but dont want to maintain the CORS setting at the product level. Any idea how to restrict a product to "read-only" operations?

Answer (score 0):

CORS is not used as a general way to permit or deny request based on verb, it's only used for actual CORS functionality: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS. Moreover CORS at product scope has its own limitations.

To do what you want, put a policy like below at product scope:

```
<choose>
    <when condition="@(context.Request.Method != "GET")">
        <return-response>
            <set-status code="401" reason="Unauthorized"/>
        <return-response>
    </when>
</choose>
```